# Rails 4 Associations: Help setting up database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, has-many-through

I need some assistance with my Rails 4 associations.  I have the following 4 models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :check_ins
    has_many :weigh_ins, :through => :check_ins
    has_many :repositionings, :through => :check_ins
end

class CheckIn < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :weigh_in
    has_one :repositioning
end

class Repositioning < ActiveRecord::Base
    # belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :check_in
end

class WeighIn < ActiveRecord::Base
    # belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :check_in
end
```

**Question:** If I am setup this way, how would I input `repositionings` and `weigh_ins` separately, but still have them linked through a single check in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to retain one of the other association's ID in order to make it work.

For example, let's say:

1. You have created a CheckIn.
2. You now add a Repositioning to that check in.
3. Store the ID of the repositioning object
4. When adding your WeighIn object, you would simply reference the correct CheckIn record: `correct_checkin_record = CheckIn.where(repositioning: the_repositioning_id)`
5. You can then add the WeighIn object to that particular record.

An alternative (and simpler) method would be to access the CheckIn directly through the User: `correct_checkin_record = @user.checkin` -- This would pull in the correct CheckIn every time.

I've included both options to help visualize exactly what is going on in the relation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to have users input weigh_ins and repositionings on different pages? 
Having weigh_ins and repositionings inputted separately but still be part of a single checkin is fine with that setup. 
Its just matter of getting the same check_in object and make the associations to that object, which can be done through the controller by passing in check_in ID params and do `CheckIn.find(params[:id])`